# Is it possible, in one query, count how much each different values occur in a column?

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

For example, a table test with one column letter,

```
letter
-------
A
B
A
A
B
A
B
```

I can think of this way

```
SELECT count(letter) FROM  test WHERE letter = 'A';
SELECT count(letter) FROM  test WHERE letter = 'B';
```

But in the above query, I need 2 select statement, and I had to specify which value to count. Is it possible to do this in one query and not specify any of the values?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can via a `GROUP BY` statement, e.g.

```
SELECT
  letter, 
  COUNT(letter)
FROM test
GROUP BY letter
```

Comment: I would use `count(*)` as it also works for NULL values. Not that this is particularly likely to be a problem here.

Comment: @a'r I don't believe that really applies here, as that wasn't a qualification in the question.  He wants a count of letters, not `null` values, where the columns may not even be nullable. ;)

Comment: And if you add a `WITH ROLLUP` to your `GROUP BY` you'll get an additional entry with `NULL` for the letter and the total SUM for all letters together as its count....

Answer (score 1):

try this (untested)

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT letter) AS LetterCount FROM test GROUP BY letter
```

Comment: This will not work. Grouping by letter then counting `DISTINCT` letters will return a 1 for every row.